# CSS: How to position divs that crosses sections

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am coding a very simple, standard landing page that has multiple sections, which look like this. It's very trendy right now. It's basically an oversized section header with lots of padding, big text, and an element that looks like it's between two sections.

I am having conceptual difficulties in how to think about positioning the cards. The cards change size fluidly, depending on viewport size, amount of text inside of them, etc.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

So far I have achieved something similar by guesstimating the size of the card (around 200px) and setting the top of the card to `-200px`. This works on my computer, but it will change in other screens, fonts, zoom level, etc. etc. I also have the problem that I get a lot of white space under the boxes, as the size of the container div is calculated without this offset.

How can I make it so that they are always perfectly centered? How can I make sure I do not have excessive white space under the cards? Thanks!!

```
<div className="bg-tertiary text-white text-center pb-10">
  <div className="bg-secondary pb-[100px] px-10">
    <h1 className="uppercase font-black text-2xl tracking-wider pt-10 pb-10 italic">HEADER TEXT</h1>
  </div>

  <div className="relative columns-4 top-[-100px] px-10">
    <MainSectionCard />
    <MainSectionCard />
    <MainSectionCard />
    <MainSectionCard />
  </div>
</div>
```

*edit*: Thanks to @wongjn for the answer!

Comment: White space is [cool](https://www.apple.com), as long as it does -- not -- generate a [false floor](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/illusion-of-completeness/). 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the top and background are both solid colors. If that is indeed the case, you could look at using a linear gradient as the background for the cards. This linear gradient can fill the colors exactly in half:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        secondary: 'darkblue',
        tertiary: 'skyblue',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div class="bg-tertiary text-white text-center pb-10">
  <div class="bg-secondary px-10">
    <h1 class="uppercase font-black text-2xl tracking-wider pt-10 pb-10 italic">HEADER TEXT</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="relative columns-4 px-10 bg-gradient-to-b from-secondary from-50% to-tertiary to-50%">
    <MainSectionCard class="block h-20 bg-white">MainSectionCard</MainSectionCard>
    <MainSectionCard class="block h-20 bg-white">MainSectionCard</MainSectionCard>
    <MainSectionCard class="block h-20 bg-white">MainSectionCard</MainSectionCard>
    <MainSectionCard class="block h-20 bg-white">MainSectionCard</MainSectionCard>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're a wizard, thanks! What if the top part is a picture? I updated the question with a second one :)

Comment: If you have a new question, consider posting it as a new post. Question posts on Stack Overflow should be about one question only.

Answer (score 0):

For second question, I think the better way is using `margin` with negative.

the html looks like blow:

```html
<Hero />
<Cards class="-mt-[100px]" />
```

you can replace the margin value with yours, and  elements before cards are not effected

Comment: Thanks XRay. But that means setting a static value, what if, because of accessibility settings (fonts set bigger than normal) the size of the card/image changes?

Comment: a good question, if the card size change, you must change the margin value every time, but you can use js to calculate the card heigth, or you can use position:relative and translateY(-50%) to resolve card height. If the card changed infrequently, the static value is easier.